# Update all data in a table without reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need some example method to update all the data in a table that fetches from database but without reloading the whole page.

Here is the form:

[image: 1]

When `Update All` is clicked it will update first row but not update with next or last row.

```
<?php include"dbConnect.php";
try { $sele=$con->prepare("SELECT*from tb2");$sele->execute();
?> 
<form method="post" name="form" action="">

<table><tr><th>Skill</th><th>Name</th></tr>
<?php while($r = $sele->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>

<tr><td> <input type="hidden" class="kdid" value='<?php echo $r["kd"];?>'>
         <input type="text" class="sklid" value='<?php echo $r["skl"];?>'> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="nmid" value='<?php echo $r["name"];?>'> </td>
</tr>

<?php } ?></table>
<input type="submit" class="upbtn" value="Update All"/></form>
<?php } catch(PDOException $e) { echo 'ERROR:' . $e->getMessage(); } ?>
<div id="look"></div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(function() {
    $(".upbtn").click(function() {
      var kode = $(".kdid").val(); var ahli=$(".sklid").val(); 
      var nama=$(".nmid").val();

      var dataString = 'kdid='+ kode +'&sklid='+ ahli +'&nmid='+ nama;

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updt.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
          $("#look").after(html);
        }
      }); return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

updt.php

```
<?php 
  include"dbConnect.php";
  if(isset($_POST['kdid'])) {
    $up=$con->prepare("UPDATE tb2 set skl='".$_POST["sklid"]."',name='".$_POST["nmid"]."' where kd='".$_POST["kdid"]."'");
    $up->execute(); 
  } 
?>
```

I think I need to make a loop, but how should I do that ?

Please give me any suggestions or code snippets that you think could be useful in solving the problem.

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: At least use  some indentation please...

Comment: @PeterTheLobster What do you mean please..?

Comment: He means the code is hard to read because there is no indentation it's just all left justified.

Comment: On my end the code is indented. I'm using Firefox under Windows 10. Is that a display issue on your end or did the OP update his questions with indents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First put array notation to each input name attribute.

```
<form method="post" id="frid">
<table>
<tr><th>Skill</th><th>Name</th></tr>
<?php foreach($sele as $r){ ?>

<tr><td> <input type="hidden" name="kd[]" value='<?php echo $r["kd"];?>'>
         <input type="text" name="skl[]" value='<?php echo $r["skl"];?>'> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="nm[]" value='<?php echo $r["name"];?>'> </td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Update All"/>
</form>
```

In client code side

```
$("#frid").submit(function() {
      $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "updt.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
          //done
        }
      }); return false;
});
```

updt.php

```
<?php include"dbConnect.php";
$id = $_POST['kd'];

if($id){
$sk = $_POST["skl"];
$ne = $_POST["nm"];
$i=0;

foreach($ne as $se) {
$up=$con->prepare("UPDATE tb2 set skl= :s, name= :n where kd= :k");
$up->bindValue('s', $sk[$i]);
$up->bindValue('n', $se);
$up->bindValue('k', $id[$i]);
$up->execute();

$i++; }
}
?>
```

This method still used serialize. Code may improve later.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted will always update the first row of values only as you specified.

The problem is that the following line for example `var kode = $(".kdid").val();` will only get the first value from the ids row and not the others.

Keep in mind that on the PHP end you're using a `while` loop so you're outputting all values whereas this is missing on the JavaScript side.

To fix this, you'll need to use something like:

```
$(".kdid").each(function(){
    var current_kode = $(this).val();
    ...
});
```

This will read all the `kdid` values one by one.

It's up to you now to decide whether to issue an AJAX request for every row or clump all rows together and then issue a single AJAX request. You will also need a way to get the values related to the `current_kode` at hand. Hint: this might be useful: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Good luck.